# TFS 2015: Release Definition REST API Issue

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, tfs, .net-core

- Visual Studio 2017 15.7.5
- .Net Core 2.1
- TFS 2015 Update 3

I'm trying to make a POST request to create a release. This is the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/integrate/previous-apis/rm/releases?view=vsts#create-a-release) I'm referring to. But I get the following error message:

> "VS402881: No artifact version is specified corresponding to artifact
>   source 'example0'. Specify a valid value and try
>   again.\",\"typeName\":\"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ReleaseManagement.Data.Exceptions.InvalidRequestException,
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ReleaseManagement2.Data,
>   Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=...\",\"typeKey\":\"InvalidRequestException\",\"errorCode\":0,\"eventId\":3000}"

This is an example of my request.

```
{
  "definitionId": 1,
  "description": "Creating Sample release",
  "artifacts": [
    {
      "alias": "example0",
      "instanceReference": [
        {
          "id": "39194",
          "name": "example"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "alias": "example0",
      "instanceReference": [
        {
          "id": "39194",
          "name": "example"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

EDIT1: Although the documentation doesn't refer to any "artifact version", I've found the variable through [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/integrate/previous-apis/rm/releases?view=vsts#get-a-release) GET call which returns a "version" under the artifacts. I've updated my Request Body with the version number as seen below but I still receive the same error.

```
{
  "definitionId": 1,
  "description": "Creating Sample release",
  "artifacts": [
    {
      "alias": "example0",
      "instanceReference": [
        {
          "id": "123",
          "name": "example0_0"
        }
      ],
      "version": {
        "id": "12345"
      }
    },
    {
      "alias": "exmaple1",
      "instanceReference": [
        {
          "id": "1234",
          "name": "example1_0"
        },
        {
          "id": "42616",
          "name": "example1_1"
        },
        {
          "id": "42617",
          "name": "example1_2"
        }
      ],
      "version": {
        "id": "123456"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution to my problem. It turns out for the Instance Reference, you need to refer to the builds not the build artifacts as one of the documentation suggests.

Answer (score 0):

The REST API to create a release in TFS 2015 is as below, you could check your api:

```
POST http://TFS2015:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/{teamproject}/_apis/Release/releases?api-version=2.3-preview.1

{
    "definitionId":1,
    "description":"",
    "artifacts":[
        {
            "alias":"CAT0604",
            "instanceReference":{
                "name":"20180621.2",
                "id":"57",
                "sourceBranch":"$/Scrum-TFVC"

            }

        }
        ],
        "isDraft":false,
        "manualEnvironments":[]

}
```

You could also press F12 and create a release in web portal to capture the api to see which part of your api is incorrect.